# Cannot convert input parameter 'myBlob' to type 'System.IO.Stream' from type 'System.ReadOnlyMemory`

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I have this issue with net7.0, dotnet-isolated: the documentation said that I can work with stream but my code crashes.

I work with these packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs" Version="6.2.0" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
```

My function is this:

```
[Function(nameof(CMImageResizer))]
public async Task Run(
    [BlobTrigger("rawimages/{name}", Connection = "StorageAccountConnectionString")] Stream myBlob,
    [BlobInput("resizedimages/{name}", Connection = "StorageAccountConnectionString")] Stream resizedImage, string name)
{
  try
   {
   _log.LogInformation("Processing image:{name} size: {myBlobLength} Bytes", name, myBlob.Length);
```

And the error code is:

```
Executing 'Functions.CMImageResizer' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): rawimages/taladro1.jpg', Id=00c22256-e65c-478c-82c3-eaca92c310b7) 
    [2023-12-24T05:35:39.632Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 2f450295-dae1-42f5-ac2e-089d5b0d2a55, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2023-12-24T05:35:38.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2023-12-24T04:42:41.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2023-12-24T05:35:28.000+00:00 [2023-12-24T05:35:40.601Z] Function 'CMImageResizer', 
    Invocation id '00c22256-e65c-478c-82c3-eaca92c310b7': An exception was thrown by the invocation. [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z] Result: Function 'CMImageResizer', Invocation id '00c22256-e65c-478c-82c3-eaca92c310b7': An exception was thrown by the invocation. [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z] Exception: Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException: 
    Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'CMImageResizer': Cannot convert input parameter 'myBlob' to type 'System.IO.Stream' from type 'System.ReadOnlyMemory1[[System.Byte, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'. Error:System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'R' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
    [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z] ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'R' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
    [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z] at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan1 bytes) [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z]    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker) [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z]    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first) [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z]    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment() [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z]    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read() [2023-12-24T05:35:40.604Z]    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
```

What's wrong, because the documentation said that now the worker allow working with stream.

Comment: At first glance, your use of strings with {name} jumps out at me. It looks like you are wanting to have {name} interpolated, but you don't have a $ sign before your strings. Am I misinterpreting your intent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like  below to not to get that error:
In BlobInput Attribute you need to keep the name of the blob as container/name.pdf and not as container/{name}

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp109
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        [BlobOutput("rithwik/{name}", Connection = "rithcon")]
        public async Task<Stream> Run([BlobTrigger("rithwikcon/{name}", Connection = "rithcon")] Stream stream, string name, [BlobInput("rithwik/applied.png", Connection = "rithcon")] Stream test)
        {
            using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

- Here, `BlobTrigger` Attribute is used for Trigger the code when or running the code when ever blob is created or modified.
- `BlobInput` Attribute is used for accessing a blob in  a specific container, it works whenever the function is triggered.
- `BlobOutput` Attribute is used to send output or return a new blob in a specific container.

**`Output:`**

Firstly uploaded a blob:

[image]

After blob is created it gets created like below because it uses BlobOutput and also you can use BlobInput in the use the content too.

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question? What change made Azure pass a Stream instead of a ReadOnlyMemory? The parameters seem to be the same, except for the altered order. The parameter attributes seem to be the same

Comment: In BlobInput Attribute you need to keep the name of the blob as container/name.pdf and not as container/{name}, this is why the error is coming @PanagiotisKanavos [BlobInput("rithwik/applied.png",connection="")] this is major and only change needed to get rid of that error. You need to give the name directly, not {}

Comment: Edit the question and point out what really solves the problem. Comments can disappear at any point. If the answer is `In BlobInput Attribute you need to keep the name of the blob as container/name.pdf and not as container/{name}` write that as the very first sentence. Don't force people to do a `diff` on the code just to understand what you're saying. Right now, the BlobInput attribute isn't even visible without scrolling.

Comment: Hi, I was enabled to copy the file to the output storage, but there is something wrong with the copy, only shows 32B and I can't open it.